# How can I use std::rotate to rotate an array of pairs whose first member is const?

Tags: c++, stl

I am implementing a map, and I would like to use std::rotate on an array of pairs, of which the first member is const (so that the key cannot be changed when inserted in the map). It is equivalent to the code below which doesn't compile:

```
#include <utility>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    typedef std::pair<const int, int> map_entry;
    std::array<map_entry, 3> a{ { {2, 0}, {1, 0}, {3, 0} } };
    std::rotate(&a[0], &a[1], &a[3]);
}
```

Unfortunately, I cannot control the type of the pair ("value_type") which needs to be defined as follows be compatible with std::unordered_map:

```
    template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A>
    class unordered_map
    {
    public:

        typedef K key_type;
        typedef std::pair<const K, T> value_type;
        typedef T mapped_type;
```

Is there way for me to use std::rotate on such an array, maybe by removing the const somehow?

Here is the compile error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 xx.cxx
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/utility:70:0,
                 from xx.cxx:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h: In instantiation of ‘std::pair<_T1, _T2>& std::pair<_T1, _T2>::operator=(std::pair<_T1 , _T2>&&) [with _T1 = const int; _T2 = int]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1610:22:   required from ‘void std::__rotate(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterat or, _RandomAccessIterator, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::pair<const int, int>*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1686:59:   required from ‘void std::rotate(_FIter, _FIter, _FIter) [with _FIter = std:: pair<const int, int>*]’
xx.cxx:9:36:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:170:8: error: assignment of read-only member ‘std::pair<const int, int>::first’
  first = std::forward<first_type>(__p.first);
        ^
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:59:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/utility:70,
                 from xx.cxx:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/move.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = const int]’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:199:23:   required from ‘void std::pair<_T1, _T2>::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1  = const int; _T2 = int]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_pair.h:256:7:   required from ‘void std::swap(std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [wit h _T1 = const int; _T2 = int]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algobase.h:147:22:   required from ‘void std::iter_swap(_ForwardIterator1, _ForwardIterator2)  [with _ForwardIterator1 = std::pair<const int, int>*; _ForwardIterator2 = std::pair<const int, int>*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1616:28:   required from ‘void std::__rotate(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterat or, _RandomAccessIterator, std::random_access_iterator_tag) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::pair<const int, int>*]’
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_algo.h:1686:59:   required from ‘void std::rotate(_FIter, _FIter, _FIter) [with _FIter = std:: pair<const int, int>*]’
xx.cxx:9:36:   required from here
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/move.h:176:11: error: assignment of read-only reference ‘__a’
       __a = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__b);
           ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/move.h:177:11: error: assignment of read-only reference ‘__b’
       __b = _GLIBCXX_MOVE(__tmp);
           ^
```

Comment: There's no template parameter in your code...?

Comment: You may be able to use `reinterpret_cast` to cast from a pointer to a pair with a `const` item to one with a non-const item.

Comment: What is the compile error you're getting?

Comment: "*compatible with std::unordered_map:*" Why must it be compatible with `unordered_map`? What do you intend to do with this array that it needs to be defined in the same way as `unordered_map::value_type`?

Answer (score 0):

Simple: don't use `std::pair`. Design a class that has the semantics that you need and use that. In particular, don't make the data members const. Instead, make them private and write accessors to enforce const-ness. `int first() const;`, `int second() const;` and `int& second();` are a good start. But they really should be named `key()` and `value()`, or something else that matches your design better.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to be compatible with std::unordered_map, which is defined as:
```template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A>
    class unordered_map
    {
    public:

        typedef K key_type;
        typedef std::pair<const K, T> value_type;
        typedef T mapped_type;
```

Comment: @greg_p -- your question **should have said that** so that people don't waste time writing answers that don't meet your unstated requirements. I've taken back my upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution. Internally, I store the pair without the const (mutable_value_type), but I still define value_type with the const and this is what is returned when you dereference an iterator for example.

```
template <class K, class T, class H, class P, class A>
class unordered_map
{
public:

    typedef K key_type;
    typedef std::pair<const K, T> value_type;
    typedef std::pair<K, T>       mutable_value_type;
```